# Multi SQL-Group by to JSON compatible form

Tags: php, json

I have a generic SQL query builder which gives me Uniform tables with the following columns:

```
Name, Name2, Amount
```

The query ends with `GROUP BY Name2, Name`.

Now i want to make it suitable to transform it into a JSON with the following gestalt:

```
{dim2: Name2, data: [{label: Name, y: Amount},{label: Name, y: Amount},{label: Name, y: Amount},...]},
{dim2: Name2, data: [{label: Name, y: Amount},{label: Name, y: Amount},{label: Name, y: Amount},...]},
{dim2: Name2, data: [{label: Name, y: Amount},{label: Name, y: Amount},{label: Name, y: Amount},...]},
{dim2: Name2, data: [{label: Name, y: Amount},{label: Name, y: Amount},{label: Name, y: Amount},...]},
...
```

So far, I made this:

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
    if(!isset($return[$result['Name2']]))
        $return[$result['Name2']] = array();

    $return[$result['Name2']][] =
        array(
            'Label' => $result['Name'],
            'y'  =>  $result['Anzahl']
        );
}
$filestring = json_encode($return, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Which doesnt work out. Working on this the whole day really got annoying and I really would appreciate some help now, thanks in advance!!!

**Update:**

Here is an example how it computes so far:

```
[{"dim2":"Consumer Entertainment","data":{"Label":"Entertainment","y":1}},
{"dim2":"Digital Life","data":{"Label":"Electronic Devices","y":1}},
{"dim2":"Digital Life","data":{"Label":"Entertainment","y":1}},
{"dim2":"Digital Life","data":{"Label":"Financial Services","y":2}},
{"dim2":"Digital Life","data":{"Label":"IT","y":2}},
{"dim2":"Digital Life","data":{"Label":"Media & Publishing","y":1}},
{"dim2":"Digital Life","data":{"Label":"Transportation & Mobility","y":1}},
{"dim2":"Healthy Life","data":{"Label":"Fashion & Accessories","y":1}},
...]
```

I want:

```
[{"dim2":"Consumer Entertainment","data":[{"Label":"Entertainment","y":1}]},
{"dim2":"Digital Life","data":[{"Label":"Electronic Devices","y":1},
{"Label":"Entertainment","y":1},
{"Label":"Financial Services","y":2},
{"Label":"IT","y":2},
{"Label":"Media & Publishing","y":1},
{"Label":"Transportation & Mobility","y":1}]},
{"dim2":"Healthy Life","data":[{"Label":"Fashion & Accessories","y":1}]},
...]
```

and so on

Comment: can't get the point. Provide a real sample.

Comment: The structure above is needed for a chart with the CanvasJS library. Dont know how to make it more clear. What are you missing?

Comment: i've done an array '[{\"dim2\":1,\"data\":[{\"l1\":\"v1\",\"l2\":\"v2\"},{\"l1\":\"v3\",\"l2\":\"v4\"},{\"l1\":\"v5\",\"l2\":\"v6\"}]},{\"dim2\":2,\"data\":[{\"l1\":\"v1\",\"l2\":\"v2\"},{\"l1\":\"v3\",\"l2\":\"v4\"},{\"l1\":\"v5\",\"l2\":\"v6\"}]}]' using json_encode without second parameter. is this what u  mean? Or you whant to make another kind of structure?

Comment: You mean leaving away the [] with: $return[$result['Name2']][] =
        array(
            'Label' => $result['Name'],
            'y'  =>  $result['Anzahl']
        );

Comment: i mean that $q=array();
        $q[]=array('dim2'=>1, 'data' => $ar);
        $q[]=array('dim2'=>2, 'data' => $ar);
        CVarDumper::dump(json_encode($q), 10, true); had the effect above. And i can't get your problem.

Comment: I added a real sample to clarify what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's much more understandable :)

```
    $ar = array('Label'=>'Entertainment', 'y'=>1);
    $q[]=array('dim2'=>'Consumer Entertainment', 'data'=>array($ar));
    $ar = array('Label'=>'Electrodivices', 'y'=>1);
    $q[]=array('dim2'=>'Digital Life', 'data'=>array($ar));
    $ar = array('Label'=>'Entertainment', 'y'=>2);
    $q[]=array('dim2'=>'Digital Life', 'data'=>array($ar));
    echo json_encode($q);
```

it gave out

[{"dim2":"Consumer Entertainment","data":[{"Label":"Entertainment","y":1}]},

{"dim2":"Digital Life","data":[{"Label":"Electrodivices","y":1}]},

{"dim2":"Digital Life","data":[{"Label":"Entertainment","y":2}]}]

So, probably you should try to write something like

```
$return[$result['Name2']][] =
    array(array(
        'Label' => $result['Name'],
        'y'  =>  $result['Anzahl']
    ));
```

how ever silly it does look. May be it doesn't understand it's taking an array? :P